# return type for the below program?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

What is the return type for this program?

I don't know what return type must be given to the following program. It is used to send multiple rows at the same time.

```
public class TimeSheetDao {
    public static final String sql= "insert into logintable values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public static int insert(List<EmployeeBean> ebList) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        System.out.println("In TimesheetDao");
        Connection conn=ConnectionProvider.getConn();
        System.out.println("before sql");

        System.out.println("after sql");
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        try { 
            System.out.println(" in try in Timesheetdao");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            for  (EmployeeBean logintable: ebList){
                ps.setString(1,logintable.getEmpid());
                ps.setDate(2,new Date(logintable.getLogindate().getTime()));
                ps.setString(3,logintable.getLogintime());  
                ps.setString(4,logintable.getLogouttime()); 
                ps.setString(5,logintable.getLunch());
                ps.setString(6,logintable.getAfterlunchlogin());  
                ps.setString(7,logintable.getAfterlunchlogout()); 
                ps.setString(8,logintable.getTask());
                ps.setString(9,logintable.getTotal());
                ps.setString(10,logintable.getOvertime());
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            int i[]= ps.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            conn.rollback();
        } 
        finally { 
            if (conn != null) {  
                try {  
                    conn.close();  
                } catch (SQLException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }
            if (ps != null) {  
                try {  
                    ps.close();  
                } catch (SQLException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  
        }  

        // What should I return here ?
        return  ?;
    }
}
```

I know the return type should be of int type. but the array of int i[]=ps.executeBatch(); cannot be returned so i dont know.

Comment: on a sidenote, rather use [try-with-ressources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if you are using java 1.7+

Comment: The return type for the class method `insert` is `int` as it is specified in the method signature ( `public static int insert(...` ). Which value you shoulf return would depend on the semantics carried by the return value.

Comment: so you're asking us to do work for you on a the basic design of a method without even knowing what the method is supposed to do or return?

Comment: it returns how many records are affected.

Comment: i know the value carries the int[] from ps.executeBatch(); I dont know how to return that value.

Comment: do you need to return those values? or not.

Comment: if i gave any int variable there it is showing incompatable types int[] cannot be converted to int

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal yes i have to return those values to servlet

Comment: `i`is just a variable in your mehtod. It may contain a value to return or it may not - that's entirely a question of the context in whih your method is to  operate, i.e. a question of your *class design*.

Comment: you return array but you get one value.you change your return type int to int[]

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal I doubt that `i` contains the number of records returned as no array is required to hold this information. However, the api docs of the classes involved are the only source of definite information here

Comment: you do not want to return anything. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get you started, read what [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) have to say about the meaning of `i`'s contents:

> an array of update counts containing one element 
>   for each command in the batch. 
>   The elements of the array are ordered according to the order
>   in which commands were added to the batch.

As you are submitting one command per `EmployeeBean` in your method's `ebList` parameter, you may want to return the sum over `i`.

However, **the only definite answer can be given by your class design** !

Comment: Thank you for the reply... i'm want to insert multiple rows like 5rows at one time

Comment: When leaving `insert`, the insert operations will have completed. This is decoupled from what you want to return from the method. What other code will use your method? Waht does that code do with the returned value ?

Answer (score 0):

The return type should be int (Integer). You can see this in `public static int...` declaration

Answer (score 0):

I would return boolean, true for successful insert, false for failure.

```
public static boolean insert(List<EmployeeBean> ebList) throws Exception {
    ...
    try{
        ...
        int i[]= ps.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();

        return true;
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        conn.rollback();
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        ...
    }
}
```